can we use metformin plus trimetazidine to reduce hyperglycemic effects in a diabetic patients if we have to use gluco corticocoid?
glucocorticoid used to reduce inflammation and other uses and if we have to use a diabetic patients it is risk to raise glucose blood level so i suggest to use metformin to induce preipherial absorption of glucose in peripherial tissues that is inhibited by glucocorticocoid and trimetazidine can help with it to induce heart to use glucose instead of fat as an energy and reduce other effects ?
